# [ORACLE]Select statement string like

Tags: oracle, select

I have this select query in oracle

```
SELECT ID_SP FROM CHITIETBAOTRI WHERE ID_SP LIKE "LOP000001"
```

and the error is

`Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LOP000001": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

I don't know why, plz help me

Comment: In Oracle strings use single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. And if you're using "like", you should probably include a wildcard character in there as well (%).

So ... something like this:

```
SELECT ID_SP FROM CHITIETBAOTRI WHERE ID_SP = 'LOP000001';
```

or

```
SELECT ID_SP FROM CHITIETBAOTRI WHERE ID_SP LIKE 'LOP%';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a match using that sequence you can use

```
SELECT ID_SP FROM CHITIETBAOTRI WHERE ID_SP LIKE '%LOP000001%'
```